# Capture an image of a dynamic chart

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, charts

My requirements:

- draw dynamic charts (pie, bars, etc.) from data provided by the user
- display a save button that allows the user to save the result as an image
- support IE 8

With modern browsers, I can use canvas for the charts, then the convenient [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) method to save the resulting chart as image. But what is the fallback for browsers like IE 8 that don't support canvas?

Comment: for IE8: render it on the server, generate a PDF server-side and provide a download.

Comment: @Diodeus thanks, but I have to use client side JavaScript. At this point, getting a pdf instead of an image would be fine with me!

Comment: There is no fallback for IE8, unfortunately. It must be done server-side.